# Postgres : Create a role and login with psql -U role

Tags: postgresql

**Code:**

```
postgres=# create role hello;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 hello     | Cannot login                                   | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

postgres=# ALTER ROLE hello WITH LOGIN;
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# ALTER ROLE hello WITH CREATEDB;
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 hello     | Create DB                                      | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

postgres=# ALTER ROLE hello WITH PASSWORD '123';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \q
-bash-4.2$ logout
[root@host test_user]# psql -U hello
Password for user hello:
psql: FATAL:  database "hello" does not exist
```

I am trying to create a role named `hello` in Postgres with `CREATE ROLE` and changed it's permission for logging in and created database. However, when I try to login with `-U` it shows me the above. Is my understanding wrong here for `-U`?

Comment: You have not created the database `hello`

Comment: Do you mean when you create a role, you need to have a database of that name?

Comment: Yes. Postgres expects that

Comment: But there is no option with `CREATE ROLE` for creating a database at the same time. I think I need to create it manually.

Comment: You have to create the database differently. Right there on the shell. `CREATE DATABASE hello;` before you can log in. Yes, manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> By default, another assumption that the Postgres authentication system
>   makes is that there will be an database with the same name as the role
>   being used to login, which the role has access to.

See here:[link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04) for more info.

After creating the database, you can then do:

```
sudo -u hello psql
```

to log in to the shell automatically.

Comment: I am able to login after creating the database. However, I see something like this `hello=>` at the shell where as with postgres it was like this - `postgres=#`. What makes the difference between the two symbols - `>` and `#`?

Comment: `#` is the prompt for a superuser account. `=>` means you are not a superuser.

Comment: Thanks. I got that.

Answer (score 0):

so i ran into a similar issue, Basically what postgres is expecting is a database that you want to choose,

And when you run the command
psql -U hello

It is assuming that you are trying to access hello database,
But by default only postgres db is created .
Try this command instead
psql -U hello postgres